# Hibernate join to class which have property of superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have following relationship:

```
class A
{
  id;
}

class B extends A
{
   //other fields...
}

class C
{
    A a; 
}
```

I want to write HQL like this:

```
select b from B as b left join C c on c.a.id = b.id.
```

but I am getting an org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!

The left join is important for me in this situation. I tried by using sub-select but there is performance issue.

Please help me :)

Comment: is there a join between b and c in the model?

Comment: @KevinBowersox c have property a which is super class for b, there is no any relation between b and c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a right join from C to A, and filter using the special property **.class** to select only items from B.

```
select a from C as c right join c.a as a
  with a.class = 'B'
```

From the [Hibernate Core Reference Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-where):

> The special property `class` accesses the discriminator value of an
>   instance in the case of polymorphic persistence. A Java class name
>   embedded in the where clause will be translated to its discriminator
>   value.